# What is the difference between MockBehavior.Loose and MockBehavior.Strict in SimpleStub?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, uwp, mocking

I'm a fresh man in VS Unit Test, and I'm learning to add mock module into my unit test project with the `SampleStub` Framework.

And I now meet the trouble in understanding `MockBehavior.Loose` and `MockBehavior.Strict`. What I truly wanna know is the difference between these two choose ? Can this choose makes a great infect to my unit test?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using `MockBehaviour.Strict` the mock behaves just like the object of the class you've mocked. It causes the mock to always throw an exception for invocations that don't have a corresponding expectation.

Thus, if the you slightly changed the class (added a method), you'll also want to add that method to the mock to make your tests pass.

`MockBehavior.Loose` on the other hand will never throw exceptions, returning default values when necessary (null for reference types or zero for value types). This is the default behaviour.